# Should I use a compatible class with @param in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc

My Python API returns a JSON object, for example:

```js
{
    a: 1,
    b: 'hi'
}
```

I also have a class for it in the client:

```js
class Sth {
    constructor() {
        this.a = null;
        this.b = null;
    }
}
```

I receive an object and pass it without modification to a function. Should I use `@param` like this, instead of a simple `@param {*}`?

```js
/**
 * @param {Sth} sth Is Sth appropriate here?
 */
function f(sth) {
    // Do sth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically interaction with an outside/thirdparty resource is typed by an [extern](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3). If you're converting the code locally, that is: fetching and using the data to create an instance then your solution is correct: the class would be enough. If however you're fetching the data and the passing it to a constructor, you'll likely want to define a type in an externs.

When getting started with externs I find the [closure debugger](https://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/) incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is appropriate. JSDocs will treat the class as a type. If the Sth class isn't available in the same file as your function you'll probably need a JSDoc type definition in that file, e.g. with `/** @typedef {import("./path/to/your/class/file.js").Sth} Sth*/`

If you can avoid `@param {*}` you generally should, since having more type information is always better!